# Java SimpleDateFormat Unparseable date

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat, parseexception

I'm having this awkward problem with simple date format.
I'm parsing some strings from a file and want to convert them in Date object.
Strings are like

```
"2012-04-19 18:33:10"
```

so my code is:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Date d1 = sdf.parse("2012-04-19 18:33:10");
```

which gives me

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-04-19 18:33:10"
```

Without the

```
setLenient(false)
```

the output date is

```
Sun Jan 01 18:33:10 CET 2012
```

which is very incorrect.

I really don't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know there were so many different combination in the pattern string. New thing learned!
Link for doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html